# Checking for failure in ajax request in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I'd like to use the .post jquery method in the coffeescript syntax to make a post request. The coffeescript documentation provides an example of adding a success callback, but doesn't provide the syntax for adding an error callback. How can I do that?

```
$.post '/',
    userName: 'John Doe'
    favoriteFlavor: 'Mint'
    (data) -> $('body').append "Successfully posted to the page."
    # Callback for error case?
```

Answer (score 1):

[You should check jQuery.post() API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jqxhr-object) or [jQuery.ajax() API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) what will give you to define both callbacks in method options.

```
$.post('/',
  userName: 'John Doe'
  favoriteFlavor: 'Mint'
  (data) -> $('body').append "Successfully posted to the page."
).fail((data) -> "Error handler")
```